# Sum up all text boxes with a particular class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a grid, with one of the columns containing a textbox, where a user can type in a dollar amount. The text boxes are declared as:

```
<input class="change-handled" sub-category-id="83" data-id="" style="text-align: right; width: 100%" type="number" value="">
```

Some are all decorated with the class "change-handled".

What I need to do, is, using javascript/jquery, sum up all the boxes which are using that class, and display the total elsewhere on the screen.

How can I have a global event, that would allow this to occur when ever I exit one of the boxes (i.e: Tab out, or ENTER out).

At the moment, I have an event which doesn't do much at the moment, which will be used:

```
$('body').on('change', 'input.change-handled', SaveData);

function SaveData() {
    var dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var categoryId = $(this).attr('sub-category-id');
    var value = $(this).val();

}
```

How can I use that SaveData event, to find all the editboxes with the 'change-handled' class, sum up their values, and display it somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the blur event.

```js
$('body').on('blur', 'input.change-handled', UpdateTotal);

function UpdateTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    var $changeInputs = $('input.change-handled');
    $changeInputs.each(function(idx, el) {
      total += Number($(el).val());
      });
  
  $('.total').text(total);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="change-handled">
<input type="number" class="change-handled">
<input type="number" class="change-handled">

Total: $<span class="total">0</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

In plain JavaScript:

```js
var changeHandled = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.change-handled'));
var total = document.querySelector('.total');

function calc() {
    total.textContent = changeHandled.reduce(function(total, el) { 
      return total += Number(el.value);
    }, 0);
}
  
changeHandled.forEach(function(el) {
   el.onblur = calc;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" class="change-handled">
<input type="number" class="change-handled">
<input type="number" class="change-handled">

Total: $<span class="total">0</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can sum up the values:

```
var total = 0;
$(".change-handled").each(function(index, box) {
    total += parseInt($(box).val(), 10);
});
```

You would then display them by using the `text` or `html` functions provided by jQuery on elements.

This can be used from anywhere in your code, including the event handler.